# Where do login credentials go when settting up PostFix SMTP relay host?

Tags: postfix

I'am setting up a external postfix relay HOST and an internal postfix server. The idea being that my internal postfix server would send emails out through the external smtpd server (both of which are using postfix). I'am using this architecture due to the fact that server#1 is used to host a webapp and an instance of postfix solely to foreward messages to server#2 my external postfix relay host for sending them. This is done as to offload the burden of sending transactional emails from my webapp server (server#1).

My setup is as follows:

In my **external** postfix server, I have changed the `mynetworks=A.B.C.D` directive in main.cf to allow for relaying from my internal postfix server.

On my **internal** postfix server I have setup sasl authentication by adding the `smtp.mydomain.com     myusername:mypassword` directive to /etc/postfix/saslpasswd.

My question is where should I add sasl authentication credentials on my relay HOST??

Also, (aside form these two directives) are there any other configuration details that I should add to my **external** postfix relay HOST to make it foreward emails comming in from my internal postfix server?

Any help would be very much appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to use the external host only as a relay for the internal host, then adding the IP to mynetworks will bypass the need for sasl auth.  You're forcing the applicaiton to auth to the internal host which is authorized to send through the external host.  I use a similar setup.

I have my postfix/dovecot server in my home and a virtual server in the cloud.  The server in the cloud uses no auth, will only allow incoming mail (from any host) to my domain(s), but allow my home IP and other vps IPs to send anything out.

You need to make sure `permit_mynetworks` is included in all smtpd restrictions in your external host like below

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2, permit
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access, permit_mynetworks, permit_auth_destination, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks
```